# Callback for ViewPager transition to next pane?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Is there any way for me to invoke a callback when the user swipes from one pane to the next? As far as my experimentation has revealed, the present (primary) pane/fragment as well as the adjacent two (to the left and right) are all 'resumed', so none of the regular fragment lifecycle callbacks are invoked.  I'm interested in this in order to hide a MediaController as soon as the pane it's associated with has been left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach an `OnPageChangeListener` to your ViewPager to get updates on when the user swipes to a new page:

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) 
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) 
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) 
    {                       
        Log.d("MainActivity", "New position = " + position);    
    }
});
```

And if you use a `FragmentPagerAdapter`, your ViewPager's pages will be cached in memory.  If you use a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, they will not be cached.

Comment: Admittedly, this is what I was looking for, but now I've discovered an additional issue: I open the ViewPager from a ListView in the previous activity. If the MediaController's pane is swiped to from an adjacent pane, it appears.  If, however, the ViewPager opens directly to the pane with the MediaController, it doesn't appear, even though at some point I got an error from the OnPageChange() method even when I opened straight to that pane. If it wasn't clear, the MediaController is attached through the OnPageChange() method. Any ideas?

Comment: I can't exactly tell what the problem is from the description.  It might be better if you posted a new question with some code snippets and a description of any errors that you're getting.

Comment: I found another way around the problem, in the end. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad you figured it out.  Good luck with everything.

Answer (score 0):

the Fragment's `setUserVisibleHint()` would be callback as long as a fragment was completely disappeared or appeared, hide or show the MediaController operation can be done here.

```
public class YourFragment extend android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
    ...
    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isVisibleToUser) {
            System.out.println("VISIBLE");
        } else {
            System.out.println("GONE");
        }
    }
    ...
}
```