# How to call animation.start() method from a Custom View when the fragment comes to foreground

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a custom Drawable Animation and I am using it in my custom `View`. Within the custom `View`, I call `animation.start()` to start the animation as described in the [animation documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html). This all works fine.

I use this custom view in a fragment in a `ViewPager`. Now my issue is that when the `Fragment` goes off the foreground and then comes back in, the animation stops and I would like it to restart. I know that I can call it from the `Fragment` but I am wondering if there is a way for the view to listen to its parent fragment's lifecycle and start the animation in the `View` itself. That would help me avoid calling the start method in each `Fragment` I use the above said custom `View`.

Comment: I think this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24847108/1294681) can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

i don't this is what you mean, but what I would do is create a method in custom view class which takes in parent fragment as input and than call the method in parent fragment using parentfragmet's reference which is responsible for starting animation

in custom view class do something like

```
private Fragment parentFrament;
public void setParentFragment (ParentFragment f){
        this.parentFragment = f;
    } 

//call parent fragment responsible for starting animation
parentFragment.startAnimation();
```

in parent fragment call this method

```
customview.setParentFragment(this);
```